# Gmail gadget not refresh although nogadgetcache=1 parameter is used

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Problem Description: deployed a new gadget xml but gadget does not refresh although parameter nogadgetcache=1 is used.
Steps to Reproduce:

1. i makes changes to a gadget xml. Deploy using Eclipse, to an appspot site.
   2, Deploy through code.google.com's google app console  ( i think this is only for changes to manifest, but with or without this step, refresh does not happen ).
2. Able to see latest changes on the appspot site hosting the gadget xml
3. logout of gmail, login with : https://gmail.com/?nogadgetcache=1
4. gmail gadget behaves like the old version.

Even stopped development for more than a week, still not refreshed.

Anyone here can help or encounter similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the gadget spec file so it uses a new URL (then update your manifest to reflect this new URL). This is from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

we have the same problem it take 30mins to get it work..

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox?nogadgetcache=1

i found the problem in chrome take's very long.. if you do it in internet explorer prived mode it much quicker..